# TeamCity Single parameter in multiple configurations

Tags: teamcity-8.0

I'm trying to increment a parameter and use it in another build configuration.

My current setup is:
Template with several parameters, 4 of which are numbers, e.g. a, b, c, d.

I have 3 build configurations based on the template.

In configuration 1 I want to increment parameter a, or use the build counter.
In configuration 2 I want parameter a to be equal to configuration 1 parameter a and increment parameter b.
In configuration 3 I want a and b to be equal to configuration 2 parameter a and b.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

I was looking at autoincremental but that seems to just increment the same parameter across multiple builds which is not what I'm after as I don't want to increment the inherited parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I used an artifact dependency to accomplish this.

Didn't originally want to use this in fear of builds to branch would cause artifact dependency to build as well, but found that would not necessary be true.